# Check standard output of a background processs in real time

Tags: files, output

Let us say I submit a process in the background and I want to see the stdout and stderr.  In [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346399/where-is-the-output-goes-when-running-as-a-background-process) it was suggested:

```
command > logfile 2>&1 &
```

But when I do head logfile I do not see anything?  Is it not real time? if not, is there anyway to print to the logfile real time?

Answer (score 1):

See [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332045/bash-force-execd-process-to-have-unbuffered-stdout).  Your problem is that writes to the file are being buffered and you need to tell them to be unbuffered to so you can see them in "real time".

The best answer there is to use the `unbuffer` script which is installed by the `expect` package on your system:

```
unbuffer command > logfile 2>&1 &
```

Comment: thanks.  my system does not have the unbuffer commmand... is there any other way? I also have a bash shell and no tcl... worse case I could ask the unix admins to install it but I am also not an admin of the system...

Comment: If the admins won't install `expect` you could compile it yourself and install it to ~/bin.